# Getting parameters from PATCH request

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I'm using the Wordpress Rest API as a CRUD-system. During POST-requests I can easily get the parameters from the request using `get_params()`.

When I want to get the params from a PATCH-request however, it returns null. After checking the request it turns out the parameters are sent in the body as a single string.

Is there any way to get these as parameters, just like in the POST-request ?

Comment: What format is the request in? If it's JSON, you might need to use json_decode.

Comment: It's form-data.

Comment: Then use this function: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php